# bootstrap-datepicker update value doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I'm trying to update the value of a datepicker for bootstrap when clicking a div, however it just does nothing (no errors). The datepicker itself works perfectly fine. Here's the javascript with the options:

```
    $('#datepicker').datetimepicker({
      format: 'DD-MM-YYYY',
      pickTime: false,
      defaultDate: moment(),
      minDate: moment(),
      maxDate: moment().add(10,'y'),
      showClose: true,
      autoclose: true,
      keepOpen: false,
    });
```

The javascript I am trying to change the date with:

```
    $('.someDiv').click(function() {
      $("#datepicker").datetimepicker('setDate', '2016-03-05');
    });
```

And finally the HTML:

```
<div class='input-group date' id='datepicker'>
    <input type='text' class="form-control" id="date"/>
    <span class="input-group-addon">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
    </span>
</div>
```

Docs can be found under following link, however the provided method doesn't work: https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

Comment: Can you create a http://jsfiddle.net/ ?

Comment: I'm trying to get a jsfiddle going, but somehow not even the normal datepicker works there. This is the current url, but it doesn't represent the status on my local environment since the datepicker itself works locally. http://jsfiddle.net/77v1f4kf/

Comment: In the fiddle you created, check for console errors.

Comment: Thanks that helped. This is my current status: http://jsfiddle.net/77v1f4kf/4/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
  $(function () {
    $('#datepicker').datetimepicker({
  pickTime: false,
  format: 'DD-MM-YYYY', 
  pickTime: false,
  defaultDate: moment(),
  minDate: moment(),
  maxDate: moment().add(10,'y'),
  showClose: true,
  autoclose: true,
  keepOpen: false
 });

    $('.date-setter').click(function() {
        alert('jj');
      $('#datepicker').data("DateTimePicker").setDate('03-05-2016');
    });

});
```

Comment: How to `setDate` dynamically?? What argument should I use? Where is the date stored before `data` is called?

Comment: Should be `data('datepicker')`

Answer (score 0):

Answer to the current version

```
$('#deadline_picker').data("DateTimePicker").date(deadline);
```